# Code from Swagger-codegen doesn't work with Flutter

Tags: android-studio, swagger, flutter, swagger-codegen

There is a problem as I want to use api library generated by *swagger-codegen* in my *flutter* project.

What I do:

1. Creating new project.
2. Generating *my_api* using *swagger-codegen*.
3. Adding created library as it is showen in *readme.md* form generated code.
4. Adding import package in project.
5. Pressing get packages button in *android studio*.
6. Adding example code as it is shown in *readme.md* from generated code.
7. (Until now everything works fine)
8. Getting an error **Not found: dart:html** (pasted below).

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
compiler message: dart:html: Error: Not found: dart:html.
Compiler failed on C:\Users\Comarch\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_with_api\lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 435

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

> I am using:
>
> - swagger-codegen (v. 2.4.0)
> - flutter (v. 0.5.1-beta)
> - android studio (v. 3.1.3)